# Comparing mean rates between two groups

Tags: t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly so please let me know what you would change. I have data that looks like this

```
day census  group   rate
1/1 453     low     .02
1/2 490     low     .04
1/3 700     high    .05
1/4 665     high    .03
1/5 567     high    .07
```

I have two census groups low and high. For this example any census below 500 is low and above or equal to 500 is in a census of high. I calculated the rates myself so I have the numerator for that and I'm using the census as the denominator.

I am currently just doing a simple t-test between the low and high groups and seeing if there is a significant difference between the rates. I also did a Mann whitney test.

I'm just wondering if I'm doing this correctly? is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: You ask about "doing this correctly" but what is "this," exactly?  What are you trying to learn from your data?

Comment: I'm trying to see if there is a significant different in the rate of adverse events between the high and low groups. i did a t test and mann whitney test on all of them. is there any other test that I can do? i may be completely overthinking this

Comment: @hospital_questions Then a t-test is appropriate, a Welch test would be used if your data does not satisfy the assumptions of the t-test. There isn't much else to say.

Comment: @user2974951 There may be quite a bit to say.  After all, this looks like a regression problem that has been shoehorned into a comparison of means by binning the explanatory variable into two groups.  It is rare to find any compelling reason to do such a thing and the loss of information in doing so indicates there must be better procedures.